Python package still unavailable after installing with venv
I know this has been answered many times but I've been through the answers and it still won't work.
I want to install package <some_package> so that I can use it through import in a script I run often.
I tried using pipx, but that obviously installs the package in a virtual environment which is then only helpful if you run the code in that virtual environment which I don't want to do.
So I followed the advice here and did:
$ python3 -m venv $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv
$ $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/python -m pip install <some_package>
$ source $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/activate

Then I tried to run my script but I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<some_package>'
Where did I go wrong?

After source $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/activate please do which python and which pip. There you can see which pip and Python your terminal is actually trying to use

How are you running your script? Are you running, e.g., python myscript.py, in which case please report back the information that @SirGamsay suggested. Or, is the script executable and starting with a shebang to define the interpreter to use (and therefore runnable with ./myscript.py) - in which case what is the shebang?

Thanks for the insight: if I run with python3 it works, if I specify python3.12 it doesn't

What is some_package? Not every Python package has the same name as the distribution package that installs it. (For example, for import yaml, you need pip install pyyaml.)

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem.
You can install the package in a virtual environment.
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install <some_package>

and run the script as follows from anywhere
without having to manually activate the environment.
$ /home/your-virtualenvironment-folder/venv/bin/python home/path-to-your-script/your_script.py

You can also add a line at the beginning of your script:
#!/home/your-virtualenvironment-folder/venv/bin/python

and run the script in the background as follows:
nohup /home/your-virtualenvironment-folder/venv/bin/python nhome/path-to-your-script/your_script.py &


So I know that the package is installed because I can see it by doing ls /home/your-virtualenvironment-folder/venv/bin.
However, even adding the line you suggested to the beginning of the script still doesn't work, I still get a ModuleNotFoundError

to see the installed packages you need to activate the virtual environment:
source venv/bin/activate
and type:
pip list

So before using this package I have to activate the virtual environment? How can I do that directly in the script? I don't want to have to do it manually each time

No, you do not have to activate the environment every time.
You activate the virtual environment and install the desired package in it. Then you can use it in a script without activating the environment, but you have to run the script giving the full path to the python binaries in that environment. /home/your-virtualenvironment-folder/venv/bin/python home/path-to-your-script/your_script.py

Try activating the virtual environment first and then install the package.
$ python3 -m venv $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv
$ source $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/activate
$ pip install <some_package>

It still doesn't work, I get the message Requirement already satisfied: <some_package> in $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/lib/python3.13/site-packages

That is not an example of it not working.
